# How can I disable access to routes unless explicitly allowed using an AuthorizeAttribute?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Using claims based identity, I currently have two different claim types. One of these claim types has much weaker security and so I want to limit the actions a user can perform when they only have the weaker credentials.

I would like to be able to specify an AuthorizeAttribute to throw onto classes where I wish to **allow** the weaker security to pass through.

I could possibly do this by having two AuthorizeAttributes and using one on the controller to deny access for the claim type and one on any routes I wish to allow, overriding the one on the controller.

How can I disable access to routes unless explicitly allowed using an AuthorizeAttribute?
Alternatively, is there a simpler way to specify that all routes will deny this claim type unless explicitly allowed?

Comment: Why not use role authorization?

Comment: Totally, accept @StephenMuecke suggestion instead reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Because we use azure, we don't want to tie too many things too closely to the web.config.

Comment: I think I'll go with an approach similar to how our application uses Authorize and AllowAnonymous, which I've discovered is as simple as registering a new global filter in the Application_Start.

Answer (score 0):

```
[AllowAnonymous] 
public ActionResult yourAction(your parameter)
{
   your logic...
}
```